# How to skip/mock the wireTap in camel route for junit test cases?

Tags: junit, mockito, apache-camel, jbossfuse, camel-spring-dsl

I have to write junit test cases for camel routes by skipping the wireTap.
Or is there possibility to mock the wireTap? If yes then how ?

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 2):

If your are wireTapping to uri "direct:foo", you can (for instance) weave your Camel route with:

```
weaveByToUri("direct:foo").replace().to("mock:junit");
```

More info at:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html